# NLTK import Error Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am very new at programming, so the following question may seem trivial. I'm currently using Python 3.4.1 with the sublime text editor (3).Since I want to use nltk, I downloaded it and I installed it succesfully. When I try to import nltk, it gives me no errors. However, whenever I want to import a corpus (e.g. Brown corpus) I get the following error:
"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\pythontest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk import brown
ImportError: cannot import name 'brown'
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\pythontest.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Xxx\Desktop]
[path: C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;$env:APPDATA\Python\Scripts]
```

"

I did install the corpora with the function nltk.download() succesfully. I seem to have problems with my python path, even though I have read about it on the internet and tried a few things, I can't seem to make it work. I'm not a mac user by the way.

Can anyone help me by telling me step by step how I can adjust my nltk to the correct python file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
```

Notice the `corpus` namespace.